# G suite契約で適切なメール送信可能件数を取得したい

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

はじめて利用させていただきます。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
現在、スプレッドシートのスクリプトからGmailの現在送れ得る残メール数を
確認する関数として`MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()`
というものを、いろいろググりまして、下記のサイトに書かれてあるコードで
利用させていただきました。

参考コード

```
function getRemainingDailyQuota(){

  max = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Browser.msgBox("本日の送信可能件数は" +max+ "件です");

}
```

引用元URL：http://googlestyle.client.jp/mail_services/class_mailapp.html

しかし、下記のように本来の上限数（私はG suite契約ですので上限2000通）でなく、
なぜか上限が100通な返り値が返ってきます。
グーグル様に質問しても、スクリプトはサポート外といった回答で、困ってしまっています。
どなたか、私の問題が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。

私の契約はG suiteなのでメール送信可能数が１日で２０００通です。
まだG suiteをはじめて１週間ほどです。
グーグル様に質問しましたが、下記のような回答もらいました。今が試用期間だとしても
上限は１００でなく５００のような気がしております。

どなたか分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、お力をお貸し願えたらうれしいです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

－－－－－－－－－－－－ご回答－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
一日あたりの送信数については、以下のヘルプ記事に記載されている数値でございます。

G Suite 本契約後 2000 通まで送信可能
G Suite 試用期間中 500 通まで送信可能

メール 1 通あたりの宛先数 100 件
1 通のメールの [To]、[Cc]、[Bcc] 欄のアドレス数。これには smtp-relay.gmail.com または smtp.gmail.com を使用して送信されたメールも含まれます*

なお、 G Suite では特定のアカウントに対してこれらの制限を変更することはございません。
そのため、ご利用されている スクリプト の対象が無料の Google アカウントか、そうでない場合には、ご利用されているスクリプト上での事象のようにお見受けいたします。

なお、問合わせの認識の確認のためとなり恐縮ですが、ご利用されているシステムは Apps Script でございますでしょうか。

誠に恐れ入りますが、Apps Script はデベロッパーによるサービスであるため、弊社では直接のサポートを提供しておりません。
－－－－－－－－－－－－ご回答終わり－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

Comment: suzukisさま ありがとうございます。
わざわざ私のために実験までしていただきありがとうございました。
こんなにも早く解決するなんて思ってもみませんでした。
どうもありがとうございました。 早苗

Answer (score 3):

1日2000通/試用期間は500通、というのは[G Suiteでのメール送信の一般的な制限](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852)です。

[Google Apps Scriptにはこれとは別の制限があり](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services)、宛先ベースで1日1500です。これを見ただけでは試用期間中の制限は自明ではありませんが、[Google Apps無償版の制限](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=ja)と最初のリンクの試用期間中の値を見比べてみると制限が同じですので、Google Apps Scriptにおいても試用期間中においてはGoogle Apps無償版と同等の制限になっていることが想像されます。

手元で試してみた結果では、`MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()`は無償版で100、有償版で1500を返します。