# GASのオーナー権限譲渡についておよび　メールリミット1500まで引き上げたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

無料gmailアカウントで、GASのスクリプトを作っています。
メール送信上限が100であることが確認されたため、
「google workspace」では1500件にアップするとのことで、移行を決め、workspaceに有料化いたしました。
GASのメール送信上限を確認するには下記の質問で既出の通り確認できましたが、
[G suite契約で適切なメール送信可能件数を取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37938/g-suite%e5%a5%91%e7%b4%84%e3%81%a7%e9%81%a9%e5%88%87%e3%81%aa%e3%83%a1%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e9%80%81%e4%bf%a1%e5%8f%af%e8%83%bd%e4%bb%b6%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

workspaceに移行したあとのスプレッドシートの権限譲渡および上限の増やし方はどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

参考に下記回答をworkspaceチームよりいただいております。
1.まず、共有ドライブに新規でフォルダを作成します
2.作成されたフォルダに入り、［メンバーを共有］ボタンをクリック
3.外部ユーザー［Gmail アカウント］のメールアドレスを入力します
4.与えたい権限を選択し、「送信」ボタンをクリック
5.「組織外のメンバーと共有しますか？」という画面が表示され「このまま共有」をクリック

上記の手順ができましたら、以下の手順に沿ってスプレットシートなどのドキュメントを移動してください。

①まず、上記でフォルダを作成されたユーザーとスプレットシートを共有ください。

②スプレットシートを移動する方法

1.移動されたいスプレッドシートなどを開き
2.スプレットシートのタイトルの隣で表示されているフォルダ→マークをクリック
3.「マイドライブ」というのが表示されている左の方の矢印をクリックし、「共有ドライブ」を選択
4.作成されたフォルダを選択し、「移動」ボタンをクリック

上記の手順でスプレットシートなどのドキュメントを移行することが可能となります。

該当フォルダのメンバーであれば誰もが管理ができますので、オーナーという権限はなくなります。

Comment: 「workspace チームからの回答」の手順は試したのでしょうか？ / こちらの質問はプログラミングからはやや外れて、web サービスのサポートに問い合わせるべき内容に見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。workspace チームの回答の通り、試しましたが、解決せず「これ以降はスタックオーバーフローに質問をお願いします」と回答が続きました。